# How to repair the EFI partition of my disk?

Tags: boot, uefi, intel

I have an Intel NUC (NUC10i7FNH2) with a NVME M2 disk. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it from a USB key. Everything works fine for quite some time but suddenly the PC crashed. It only runs a simple Python web server and was thus not linked to a screen. I shut it down and connected it to a screen and a keyboard. When trying to restart, I got the following message

```
A bootable device has not been detected.
```

I booted from the USB key and I could find my disk. It had 2 partitions: an EFI System Partition and the Linux Filesystem.

I ran *fsck* on the 2 partitions. On the second one, with the filesystem, it found some issues that it solved. On the EFI partition, it failed with

```
Bad magic number in super block while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Is it possible and how can I repair my EFI partition without losing my data in the other partition ?

Comment: Hello. Sounds like the drive has failed. Time to replace it.

Comment: Your EFI is a FAT partition, did you use dosfsck on it?

Comment: I tried dosfsck but I also got an error. So I ended up copying the most important files and then reinstalling everything

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on the internet maybe can work with your situation

```
Solution
1) Find the backup of superblocks using dumpe2fs or mke2fs

dumpe2fs will work on mounted or unmounted disk but mke2fs require disk unmounted.
You can try this.
#dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdb

[root@sss ~]# dumpe2fs /dev/sdb |grep -i superblock
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-2
Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32770
Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98306
Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-163842
Backup superblock at 229376, Group descriptors at 229377-229378
Backup superblock at 294912, Group descriptors at 294913-294914
Backup superblock at 819200, Group descriptors at 819201-819202
Backup superblock at 884736, Group descriptors at 884737-884738
Backup superblock at 1605632, Group descriptors at 1605633-1605634
Backup superblock at 2654208, Group descriptors at 2654209-2654210
OR THIS
[root@sss ~]# #mke2fs -n /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
720896 inodes, 2883584 blocks
144179 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the superuser
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=2952790016
88 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32769, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208

2) Replace the superblock using the backup superblock

#fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb
or
#mount sb=32768 /dev/sdb /mountpoint
or
#e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb

If we are getting the same error with superblock located on 32768, repeat the step with another superblock location.
```

I don't know if it can work but I've seen two more posts that deal with the same problem as this one, hope it works for you.
[This is where I found the posibly solution][1]
[1]: https://www.serveradminz.com/blog/bad-magic-number-in-superblock/

Comment: Thanks for this solution ! Unfortunately, it did not work for me. As I understand it, this only works for ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions. However, the faulty partition in my case was the EFI one which is formatted with FAT. I ended reinstalling everything, after backing up the most important files